# How do I Force Move (pull) a weapon or item out of someone's hand?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars

I've read the rules of the Move power a few times. *If* I lift an object I need to make a discipline roll against the silhouette of the thing lifted. *But* if I try to pull something out of another's grasp I'm not sure what the roll is.

I *think* I read something about a contested discipline roll, but I haven't been able to find the rule again. **If I use pull to relieve someone of an item or weapon, what exactly do I have to roll for that?**

(Primarily under force & destiny rules but also under the other rules where applicable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAW there is nothing you can do to resist being disarmed with the Move power.
But if the players start abusing it, you can house rule to be resisted by Discipline or even rule that they need the same number of advantages that they need on attack rolls (3).
Keep in mind that when attacking, you can spend 3 advantages to disarm someone and they cant do anything about it. But then, the "resistance" is the difficult dice being rolled.

Comment: The RAW do cover this question in Edge of the Empire and Age of Rebellion. One of the Control Upgrades for Move is the ability to remove an object from a person's grasp. This may be resisted IF the character affected is important enough (Nemesis, Rival, PC) using appropriate traits, such as Discipline but not limited to it. Christopher has posted  this as well: "Pulling Out of Their Grasp"

Comment: You are correct, his answer should be edited to be the answer to this question.

Answer (score 8):

### Pulling Out of Their Grasp

Per the control upgrade on Force and Destiny Beta p210: "*The Force user gains the ability to pull objects off secure mountings or from an opponent's grasp.*"

There is no roll against most enemies. However…

### Opposed Force Power Checks

Page 195 of *Force and Destiny Beta* says:

> When a Player Character or powerful Non-Player Character (generally a
>   nemesis, but sometimes a plot-important, named rival) wishes to use a
>   Force power against another PC or powerful NPC, the GM can decide to
>   make the Force power check an opposed check, if it is not already…The
>   skills used in the check are up to the GM and the players involved…

The default is Discipline for the active Force user, and the defender can also default to Discipline if they are also a Force-user.

Minor NPCs and minions don't get a check, since they're not important enough, and therefore the Force-user doesn't need to roll, either.

Comment: "...doesn't need to roll, either."  Except for the check, using Force Dice, to make sure they can actually activate the power, of course.  Just no *opposed* roll.

Comment: This should be flagged as the correct answer to this question.

Comment: The sidebar for this is found on page 283 of Force and Destiny (Resisting Force Powers) and the Move power covers its usage for the other games if the group does not wish to incorporate this rule in EotE and AoR.

Answer (score -1):

I would be inclined to do an opposed roll, against the holder's Athletics skill, or perhaps Coordination.

I believe that Force and Destiny has some specifics on this.